# How to prevent loose skin when losing lots of weight

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight, skin

I am a very overweight man at 385 lbs (175 kg).  I've been this weight for over a decade.  I've started a new eating & exercise program in order to lose 185 lbs.

One thing that worries me is I've seen many websites and YouTube videos showing loose, hanging skin.  Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening as I lose the weight?

Answer (score 6):

The younger you are, the more likely your skin is to return to a more "normal" or "tight" state. However, depending on the length of time the skin has been stretched, the extent to which it has been stretched (think about really bad stretch marks) it might not return to that "normal" state even at a young age.

One of the only solutions I know of is surgery. I hope someone else can answer this that might have heard of a less invasive solution.

Comment: No, that's pretty much about it. The younger and less heavy you are, the more likely it is that at least some of it will retract/resile, but many many people that lose large amounts of weight (50kg+) have cosmetic surgery to remove the loose folds of skin that remain.